# Duplicate entries generated by stristr

Tags: php

I keep getting duplicate entries (4 to be exact) when using stristr to filter a JSON by keywords.  An example of my code is as follows:

```
$keywords = array('small','medium','large');

foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
foreach ($data as &posts) {
    if(stristr($posts['message'],$keyword) !== FALSE ) {
        print_r($posts);
        }
        }
        }
```

When I do the following there are zero duplicates:

```
foreach ($data as &posts) {
    print_r($posts);
    }
```

I have tried `array_uniq` but with no success.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?  Is there a better way to sort JSON?

Comment: change this:     if(stristr($posts['message'],$keyword) !== FALSE ) { to this:     if(stristr($posts['message'],$keywords) !== FALSE ) {
may be ?

Comment: your `$keyword` is missing the `s` at the end. make sure you're using the same variable.

Comment: My apologies to Maximus2012 and mavili. You are both correct about the $keyword.  I made the mistake of not including a line of code in the example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the duplicate posts match more than one keyword? If so, they'll be printed for each match.

If you want to print each post only once per match, loop through the posts first, and quit checking a post when a keyword match is found:

```
foreach ($data as &posts) {
  foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
    if(stristr($posts['message'],$keyword) !== FALSE ) {
        print_r($posts);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked but still have some duplicates(2x).  Originally I had 4 duplicates now only 1 extra set.

Comment: Hard to say more without seeing data. Can't replicate that here.

Comment: Finally got it to work!!! Thanks Paul Roub,  mavili, and Maximus2012!!.  I added the `break;` after the loop then preformed the `array_uniq` function and IT WORKED!